Why centripetal acceleration does not causes the rotating particle to reduce the radius of its circular path?
I think that the centripetal force must develop a corresponding centripetal velocity that keeps on increasing as time passes because, $v = u + at$
Centripetal velocity constantly increases in terms of magnitude, but the tangential velocity is always constant in terms of magnitude. So adding both of the velocities vectorially will give us a vector that gradually goes closer to centripetal velocity and centripetal velocity should change the radius of the circular motion.
I've seen Is Centripetal Velocity a Thing?
But that really didn't answer why centripetal velocity do not exist. I request you to answer why centripetal velocity do not exist?

Why do you think that $v = u + at$ is relevant when $a$ isn't a constant? It's a vector that varies with time.


Centripetal velocity constantly increases in terms of magnitude

Just think about it, what you are saying  would work in the case when the body is in rest ( but that's not the case , it is rotating ).
Let me explain:
In a small time interval $dt$ , one could imagine the rotating body to have a constant acceleration ( i.e. const. direction along with const. magnitude) . During this period ,the acceleration does add a velocity toward the centre , but it have such a small magnitude that what it does is just rotate the initial velocity vector through a small angle $dθ$ as shown in the figure ( not to scale ).And , the effect ( the increase of the magnitude of centripetal velocity in a particular direction ) doesn't get accumulated . (Why? ,due to the rotation, since the acceleration vector itself get turned and hence couldn't provide velocity in a particular direction for long enough).See it:At the two points  $A$ and $B$ in the previous figure , the amount of centripetal velocity ( shown by the blue vector ) added by the acceleration is denoted as $\vec{v}_{c}^{A}$ and $\vec{v}_c^B$ .
Clearly, as the acceleration vector is turning , it adds the centripetal velocity in different directions ( the added velocity at B has nothing to with that at A and even it's direction is different ) which shows that the centripetal velocity is not accumulating in a particular direction and hence doesn't and can't change the original velocity's magnitude.

The answer is awesome and it really did solve my problem, but it's a little request. Can you please elaborate the answer that explained why effect doesn't get accumulated?

@Peterswift sorry for the confusion, by " the effect" ,I meant the increasing magnitude of the centripetal velocity ( as quoted by you ) . Now , since the acceleration change its direction every time , so the velocity towards the centre doesn't get accumulated and change the original velocity. If there is still a confusion, please let me know.

"the acceleration vector itself get turned and hence couldn't provide velocity in a particular direction for long enough", but the acceleration vector is always directed towards the center and hence the centripetal velocity.

The perpendicular velocity of the particle is also changing but, if I did something to the particle that accelerates it then also it would get accumulated.

@Peterswift Don't just observe the head of the acceleration vector.... it's spatial direction in the coordinate space changes continuously.Just read it carefully and imagine the thing  , hopefully you would understand.

Yeah about the the non uniform circular motion .. the tangential acceleration would always keeps increasing/ decreasing the tangential velocity....which could be said as an accumulation.

Thank you so much. I might give it a go.

@CP of Physics, I think I got you. Are you trying to say that at point A in the coordinate system, Vc is developed but just an instant after A, let the new point be B, Vc is developed from scratch and is not added to the previous one because acceleration increases speed in a particular direction.

@Peterswift yes , acceleration increase speed in its own direction.

Thanks a lot sir

@Peterswift you are always welcomed .

@CpofPhysics Sir, can you help me with a small problem? Am I correct in saying that when you rotate a stone by tying a string to it, from the stone's point of view, it is at rest because the centrifugal force balances the inward force (which, in an inertial frame, would be known as the centripetal force)?

@Peterswift Don't call me sir ...just as a friend. Now to your question, what you are missing is the tension in the string. Also in any frame you can't consider both centripetal and centrifugal force acting on the same object.
